# Capturing multiple groups via regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a function that locates a single group which perfectly working perfectly

```
public static Optional<String> locateInText(String text, Pattern pattern) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    return matcher.find() ? Optional.of(matcher.group(1)) : Optional.empty();
}
```

Now I am trying to build up a function that locates 2 groups and concatenates them and returns the value in String if two groups do not exist return 1 group

```
public static Optional<String> locateInTextt(String text, Pattern pattern) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        if (matcher.groupCount() > 1) {
            int sum = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) + Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
            return Optional.of(String.valueOf(sum));
        } else if (matcher.groupCount() == 1) {
            return Optional.of(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

The test did work if there are two matches but if there is just one it keeps returning empty, what I am missing, I read some information and it seems to be possible to indicate group as optional, would appreciate any advice

Use case text:

> Всего 2 Коробки, 193 Короб-шкафа

in that case, I need both groups captured, which is 2 and 193 = 195

Second use case text;

> Всего 2 Коробки

Third use case text

> Всего 193 Короб-шкафа

```
 Pattern.compile("Всего\\s*(\\d*)\\s*Коробки,\\s*([\\d,]*)\\s*(?:Короб-шкаф[ова]*|Коробо*к[аи]*)");
```

Answer (score 0):

according to your post, you would want to match string and substrings within, I cannot think of proper solution. However, your problem is easy, if we omit  "Всего", then we can do following:

```
"((\\d*)\\s*Коробки|\\s*([\\d,]*)\\s*(?:Короб-шкаф[ова]*|Коробо*к[аи]*))"
```

to find either string with "Коробки" or another string

Comment: Hey thank you for your comment, i need to either find 1 group or both groups , in your case it looks like its one group or another

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? I didn't use the methods you provided though since the basic requirement you mentioned can be achieved through a simple `Matcher.replaceAll()` call.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Всего\\s*(\\d*)(\\s*Коробки,?)?(\\s*([\\d,]*)\\s*(?:Короб-шкаф[ова]*|Коробо*к[аи]*))?");
String replacement = "$1 $4";
String text = "Всего 2 Коробки, 193 Короб-шкафа";
System.out.println( p.matcher( text ).replaceAll( replacement ) );
```

This considers the string "Всего" to be present in the input always.

Comment: Hey this wasn't really what i wanted to achieve , but thank you so much for your comment, i have approached  another way of capturing the result , thank you for your time,your comment is still very useful

Comment: Oh. Sorry about getting the requirement incorrect. Is it possible for you to post here what you finally used?